# How I can add the molecular Weight of my new list of strings using a mw dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, biopython

I am trying to digest this string with formic acid, but I am trying to calculate each fragment I get after the digestion, and I just want to know ways how I can add the values of my dictionary into my new set of list.  (Any advice will be much appreciated)

```
import string

aa_seq = 'MLCPWNFLLKPRYRGKYEPGSSPAADLNNNEKGIGNEKSLVNGHIPNCETINPhSKSFP'

formic_acid = aa_seq.replace('A', 'A|').replace('N', 'N|').upper().split('|')

formate = list(formic_acid)

weights = {'A': 71.04, 'C': 103.01, 'D': 115.03, 'E': 129.04, 'F': 147.07,
           'G': 57.02, 'H': 137.06, 'I': 113.08, 'K': 128.09, 'L': 113.08,
           'M': 131.04, 'N': 114.04, 'P': 97.05, 'Q': 128.06, 'R': 156.10,
           'S': 87.03, 'T': 101.05, 'V': 99.07, 'W': 186.08, 'Y': 163.06 }
weight = []

for acid in formate:
    weight = weight + weights[acid]
print "The molecular weight of this protein is", weight
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "r.py", line 15, in <module>
    weight = weight + weights[acid]
KeyError: 'MLCPWN'
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this `formic_acid = aa_seq.replace('A', 'A|').replace('N', 'N|').upper().split('|')` line?

Comment: The purpose is to cut specifically, every A and every N of the string as protein digest, this acid is very specific in thse regions, and what I have in return is chunks of the fragments cut by this enzyme, but I am trying to calculate with the dictionary the values for each of thse fragments in my split list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the sum of the weights get the sum of each letter in acid:

```
for acid in formate:
    weight = sum(weights[a] for a in acid)
print "The molecular weight of this protein is", weight
```

If you want the weight and acid in a list:

```
weight_list = []
for acid in formate:
    weight = sum(weights[a] for a in acid)
    weight_list.append((acid,weight))
    print "The molecular weight of this protein is", weight



aa_seq = 'MLCPWNFLLKPRYRGKYEPGSSPAADLNNNEKGIGNEKSLVNGHIPNCETINPhSKSFP'

formic_acid = aa_seq.replace('A', 'A|').replace('N', 'N|').upper().split('|')

weights = {'A': 71.04, 'C': 103.01, 'D': 115.03, 'E': 129.04, 'F': 147.07,
           'G': 57.02, 'H': 137.06, 'I': 113.08, 'K': 128.09, 'L': 113.08,
           'M': 131.04, 'N': 114.04, 'P': 97.05, 'Q': 128.06, 'R': 156.10,
           'S': 87.03, 'T': 101.05, 'V': 99.07, 'W': 186.08, 'Y': 163.06 }

weight_list = []
for acid in formic_acid:
    weight = sum(weights[a] for a in acid)
    weight_list.append((acid,weight))
    print "The molecular weight of the protein {} is {}".format(acid,weight)
print(weight_list)

The molecular weight of the protein MLCPWN is 744.3
The molecular weight of the protein FLLKPRYRGKYEPGSSPA is 2047.06
The molecular weight of the protein A is 71.04
The molecular weight of the protein DLN is 342.15
The molecular weight of the protein N is 114.04
The molecular weight of the protein N is 114.04
The molecular weight of the protein EKGIGN is 598.29
The molecular weight of the protein EKSLVN is 670.35
The molecular weight of the protein GHIPN is 518.25
The molecular weight of the protein CETIN is 560.22
The molecular weight of the protein PHSKSFP is 780.38
[('MLCPWN', 744.3), ('FLLKPRYRGKYEPGSSPA', 2047.0599999999995), ('A', 71.04), ('DLN', 342.15000000000003), ('N', 114.04), ('N', 114.04), ('EKGIGN', 598.29), ('EKSLVN', 670.3499999999999), ('GHIPN', 518.25), ('CETIN', 560.22), ('PHSKSFP', 780.3799999999999)]
```

To get min and max just keep track through the loop:

```
mx = None
mn = None
for acid in formic_acid:
    weight = sum(weights[a] for a in acid)
    if mx is None or weight > mx:
        mx = weight
    if mn is None or weight < mn:
        mn = weight
    weight_list.append((acid,weight))
    print "The molecular weight of the protein {} is {}".format(acid,weight)
print("The minimum and maximum weights are:  {}, {}".format(mn,mx))
```

Comment: it Worked but, it is possible to calculated by each of the chunks produced by the cleavages for example: ['MLCPWN', 'FLLKPRYRGKYEPGSSPA', 'A', 'DLN', 'N', 'N', 'EKGIGN', 'EKSLVN', 'GHIPN', 'CETIN', 'PHSKSFP'], because the output calculates the first chunk but not the rest, how I can get a set of each fragment with its corresponding molecular weight?

Comment: Just make a dictionary `chunk_weights = {}` then inside the loop do `chunk_weights[acid] = weight` after the sum. You will have issues with the 2 `'N'`s

Comment: @kelvin30, you don't need to use `list(formic_acid)` , I will add a full working example

Comment: I really appreciated, also I discovered an error in the meantime, I discovered that formic acid cuts only at letters 'D' from the string, sorry for the errors and not being very specific.  With the correct cut the output result iit will return this list: ['MLCPWNFLLKPRYRGKYEPGSSPAAD', 'LNNNEKGIGNEKSLVNGHIPNCETINPHSKSFP']
This is using instead of 'A' & 'N' is using the correct string digestion with 'D'.

Comment: @kelvin30. Unless I am not understanding you the approach should be the same

Comment: Yes the approach is correct this helped, many thanks, I really appreciated, this was the approach.

Comment: Also and sorry to keep bothering you, exist a way with this output to specify the maximum value and the minimum?  Is just to sort the values, and if is possible?

Comment: @kelvin30, I will add to my answer the most efficient was is to just keep track as you go, if you want the protein name also just add a variable to keep track of each just like mn and mx

Comment: no worries. You could call min or max on the list but doing it in the loop is most efficient

Comment: I have it as if statements but just to see another advise

Comment: @kelvin30, is that a question or a comment ;)

Comment: Sorry to ask you again, but how can be this approach as a functions?

Comment: @kelvin, simply def func_name(): and put all the code inside the function making sure to `return weight_list` if you want to use it

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged with Biopython, what about using it?

```
from Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParam import ProteinAnalysis


prot = ProteinAnalysis(
    "MLCPWNFLLKPRYRGKYEPGSSPAADLNNNEKGIGNEKSLVNGHIPNCETINPhSKSFP".upper())

# Biopython adds a water molecule to every aminoacid.
print prot.molecular_weight() - 18.02
```

That's it! Lets introduce the chain splitting. I think you'll be better served with `re.split`:

```
import re
from Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParam import ProteinAnalysis


prot = "MLCPWNFLLKPRYRGKYEPGSSPAADLNNNEKGIGNEKSLVNGHIPNCETINPhSKSFP".upper()

for peptide in re.split("(A|N)", prot):
    print peptide, ProteinAnalysis(peptide).molecular_weigth() - 18.02
```

Comment: Thank you, is another approach appreciated!

Comment: Also if I want this to be built in a small function how will look like?

Comment: This is almost a function. Pass the sequence and the split term to the function. Do the "upper", split and create the returning dict/list of tuples.

Comment: As padraic said, wrap the code with `def function_name(arg1, arg2)`, and you're good to go. http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/declaring_functions.html

Answer (score -1):

Change the following lines,

weight_list = []

weight = 0

for acid in formate:

```
    for w in acid:
            weight = weight + weights[w]
    weight_list.append(weight)
```

print "The molecular weight of this protein is", weight_list